# gnuplot not working on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, unix, png, gnuplot

My initial problem is that i am unable to find png as list of terminals in set term. So using the link https://askubuntu.com/questions/393882/png-terminal-in-gnuplot, I installed the gd library.And then i installed gnuplot4.6.4. But when gnuplot is not working. I get the following error:

```
gnuplot: error while loading shared libraries: libgd.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

My system description is

```
 Linux masterx-Studio-1535 3.5.0-27-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 25 20:00:05 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

In the path /usr/lib:
I have libgdata.so.13    and  libgdata.so.13.4.1.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you installed the version 2 and not 3. Check what you have in /usr/lib if there is either 2 or 3.

The libgd version 3 package is named "libgd3"

Comment: in the path i have libgdata.so.13   and   libgdata.so.13.4.1. What should i do next. Please guide..

Comment: The missing library is not libgdata but libgd! You should have a file like libgd.so.3 (or libgd.so.2). Try checking in case also in /usr/lib/i386-linux/ for the file.

Shortly I suggest an "apt-get install libgd3"